# Are there any guidelines for having a low risk of getting audited by IRS?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs, audit

I know the question might be too broad. But maybe top 5-10 guidelines will suffice.

Comment: I found my answer here - http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/7783/what-increases-your-chance-of-being-audited?rq=1.  Closing

Answer (score 2):

The issue isn't avoiding the audit. The issue is being able to pass the audit.

Claim everything you are entitled to claim, report everything that has to be reported and you will be fine.

If the IRS suspects a higher then normal amount of fraudulent reporting for a specific situation, and you fall into that situation then you have a higher then normal chance of getting audited. But you have the right to claim and report accurately. If you did so then you will pass the audit.

If you want to avoid virtually all audits:

- Report everything you are required to: all income from your job, your bank, your investments. The IRS does have copies of these documents.
- Claim only what is on the W-2 or on the form regarding taxes and interest from your mortgage company.
- If what you can claim under the previous bullet is under the standard deduction take it. If it is over the standard deduction then claim the higher amount.

You avoid the audit because the chances of you owing additional tax is essentially zero. Of course that means that you may skip claiming some deductions you could have taken.